# ER Diagram about car rental company

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I am generating an ER Diagram about a car rental company that stores information about the cars, their makes, models, and colors. Would I classify the make, model, and colors as separate entities, or as attributes of the car entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would make sense if the make, model, and color themselves have attributes (e.g., a color can have attributes like heat retention or reflectiveness). Using the BCNF principles, you wouldn't want to replicate these properties per car, but hold them once per color, and have the different cars reference this color.

Otherwise, if they are just simple properties, it doesn't make much sense to store them as entities on their own right.